# How to save a nested object in separate models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-serializer

I'm trying to save a nested object into two different tables in my Django app. I'm missing something because I get validation errors from the sub Model. The data in my `events` is not recognized and the serializer validation fails. Do I need to modify my serializer somehow or is there something wrong with my Models?

I have these two Models:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PlanEvent(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    done = models.BooleanField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Then I have these serializers for my Models:

```
class PlanEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlanEvent
        fields = '__all__'


class PlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = PlanEventSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        fields  = ('name', 'events')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        events_validated_data = validated_data.pop('events')
        plan = Plan.objects.create(**validated_data)
        plan_event_serializer = self.fields['events']
        for p in events_validated_data:
            p['plan'] = plan
        events = plan_event_serializer.create(events_validated_data)
        return plan
```

In my `views.py` I do this:

```
class PlanView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny,]
    serializer_class = PlanSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I try to save a Plan and the PlanEvent into their own table with this payload:

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "events": [
    {
      "done": false,
      "title": "some title"
    },
    {
      "done": true,
      "title": "some title"
    }
  ]
}
```

This gives me an error message 400 Bad Request every time:

```
    {
    "events": [
        {
            "plan": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        },
        {
            "plan": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It seems, you need to pass plan primary key, not plan object in serializer.
`for p in events_validated_data:`
 `p['plan'] = plan.id`

Comment: @Yerycs Thank you for your suggestion but that doesn't seem to work. The code doesn't actually ever get to that `create` -method, it fails in this row: `serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)` in `class PlanView`.

Comment: Please specify each field in PlanEventSerializer (not using __all__ ). but not includes plan foreign key field.

Comment: @Yerycs Thank you, that was needed, also had a typo which was causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I had a mistake in here:

```
 for p in events_validated_data:
     p['plan'] = plan
```

It was supposed to be:

```
 for p in events_validated_data:
     p['id'] = plan
```

Also had to exclude the foreign key field from the serializer as Yery cs suggested.

Answer (score -1):

It seems, you need to pass plan primary key,not plan object in PlanSerializer.

```
for p in events_validated_data:
            p['plan'] = plan.id
```